# Arduino Serial Communication list doesn't get fully sent through python

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I have an issue with sending serial data through python. Let me explain it this way. I have a motor code on arduino which receives data from serial and moves through the received data. 
However, whenever I send data in this case 8 lists, it doesn't read the 8th list.
By playing with time.sleep in python code I could see some differences(I could see 4 lists being sent,then I increased time.sleep to 8 and now it sends 7 lists.)
I know playing with time.sleep isn't a solution though. I have also tried emptying input and output buffers and I am out of ideas on what to do next. Here are the codes.
The Python Codes:
The incoming byte will be the data sent as you can see with a for loop, I am sending the lists. The first three values inside each list is to control functions. 1,0,0 means that it will only work the motor function which I have shared in the arduino part. The 3rd and 4th variables here are for controlling the motor, meaning 1st motor will turn 2000 steps and the other will turn for a 1000 steps.

```
import time
import serial
def close():
    arduino=serial.Serial("COM4",9600)
    time.sleep(7)    
    incomingByte=[[1,0,0,2000,1000,1000],[1,0,0,200,100,1000],[1,0,0,250,650,1000],[1,0,0,1000,1000,1000],[1,0,0,2000,1000,1000],[1,0,0,200,100,1000],[1,0,0,250,650,1000],[1,0,0,1000,1000,1000]  
    length= len(incomingByte)
    for i in range(uzunluk):
       arduino.write(str.encode(str(incomingByte[i])))
       arduino.reset_input_buffer()
       arduino.reset_output_buffer()
       time.sleep(7)
    arduino.close()

close()
```

The Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(stepPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(endstop1, INPUT);
  pinMode(endstop2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

void motor(){

  for (i=0; i < incomingdata[3]; i++) {
     digitalWrite(stepPin1,HIGH);
     delay(2);
     digitalWrite(stepPin1,LOW);
     delay(2);
    }
  for (i=0; i < incomingdata[4]; i++) {
     digitalWrite(stepPin2,HIGH);
     delay(2);
     digitalWrite(stepPin2,LOW);
     delay(2);
    }
  act_motor=0;
  delay(incomingdata[5]);
  Serial.flush();
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()){
    for (a=0; a < 6; a++) {
      incomingdata[a] = Serial.parseInt();
    }
    identifier=(incomingdata[2]);
    act_enable=(incomingdata[1]);
    act_motor=(incomingdata[0]);
  }
  if (identifier) homee();
  if (act_enable) Enable();
  if (act_motor) motor();
}
```

To simply explain the arduino code; according to the serial data the 3rd and 4th data from each array will be step numbers of how much the stepper motors will move. The 5th data on the list will be the delay for each of the motors kept waiting. 
I hope I explained this clearly. I would be glad if anyone could help. 
P.S: I am sorry If I have violated any rules. I will be sure to correct my mistakes.

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=416608.msg2869092#msg2869092

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33643802/edit

Comment: So this is kind of a synchronization problem, right? Will try out and reply after I have tried this method.

Comment: Btw how do I debug this? I can't open serial monitor when I am sending the data. Is there an easy way for me to do this? I would be glad if anyone could help out on the subject as well.

Comment: Arduino side: https://www.instructables.com/id/HOW-TO-use-the-ARDUINO-SERIAL-MONITOR/ In Python you can just print what was received.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that the numbers and the order are correct on the Arduino side?

You should always be careful with functions like `parseInt` that just start somewhere and do some magic.

I recommend to separate your messages using something like `\r\n`. Then use the normal `read()` until that sequence is found and until then throw everything away.

Then use `parseInt` (if you have to) for six times. Then repeat and start looking for the `\r\n` using `read()` again.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked the numbers and they are correct. As I have mentioned , the code works fine for a good length however, after some point it goes crazy but will try out this method and will reply under this thanks